# HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script - .htaccess doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, html, boilerplate

I thought I'd try out the Build Script for HTML5 Boilerplate - it's aimed at front-end designers and developers so this should be fairly straightforward right?

I'm running with a Mac so I should have all I need according to Paul.

Tried it on a blank project and immediately hit a brick wall.

1. I ran the cd build command, pointing it to my local folder
2. Then I ran ant build. It seemed to go OK, with a load of jibberish about how it was Building a Production environment but got stuck when looking for the htaccess file...

> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/jaygeorge/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/HTML-Sandbox/build/build.xml:137:
>   The following error occurred while
>   executing this line:
>   /Users/jaygeorge/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/HTML-Sandbox/build/build.xml:673:
>   Replace: source file
>   /Users/jaygeorge/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/HTML-Sandbox/publish/.htaccess
>   doesn't exist

Well of course the .htaccess file doesn't exist because it didn't come with the Boilerplate download. Do I need to download the htaccess file from my website so that it sits locally? I don't really understand this stuff - Was hoping Paul Irish would make his instructions more comprehensive :-(.

Comment: There should be an `.htaccess` file in the root folder of the ZIP file, is it not there?  Note that you may have to turn on 'view hidden files' or similar to see it.

Comment: Cheers, that worked. Can you post it as a solution and I'll flag it as an answer - should give you good rep.

Comment: I copied my comment down to the answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be an .htaccess file in the root folder of the ZIP file you downloaded.  Note that you may have to turn on 'view hidden files' or similar in your File Explorer to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make empty .htaccess file and copy/paste code from: http://html5boilerplate.com/